# Where could I find docker-standard environment variables like DOCKER_HOST?

Tags: maven, docker, environment-variables

I'm using docker-maven-plugin. And it said -

"By default the plugin will try to connect to docker on localhost:2375. Set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable to connect elsewhere.
`DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<host>:2375`
Other docker-standard environment variables are honored too such as TLS and certificates.".

After I protect the Docker daemon socket reference to https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/. I think I need to set some variables like `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"` and also variable which is used to locate ca.pem file. So where could I find these docker-standerd environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You would find (and set) them on the same user that is running the docker-client.

EG:

```
nick@primestorage01:~$ set | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=terrorbyte:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=true
```

You can do that many ways for an interactive login. One way is via a .bashrc file. (assuming you are using bash)

In .bashrc, you can add these lines:

```
#docker

export DOCKER_HOST=terrorbyte:2376
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=true
```

If this is some sort of automation, depending on your methodology .bashrc won't be called (Specifically, if it's a non interactive shell such as via `ssh host COMMAND`. In this case, you'll need to set the environment variables another way.

PS, make sure you also put the certificates in the expected directory to make your life easier. The expected directory is `~/.docker`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And another question is when I access remote docker daemon, like `docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem \
  -H=$HOST:2376 version`. There are there certificates, should I directly copy all of these(ca.pem, cert.pem, key.pem) to `~/.docker` directory? How could docker distinguish them?